# Getting the difference List of two different List Objects in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I tried getting the difference two different List objects in VB.NET

Below is the code which I tried.

```vb
myList3 = myList1.Where(Function(item) myList2.Any(Function(item2) item.ClassId <> item2.Id))
```

But I got casting error

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `` WhereListIterator`1[MyProj.CategorVO] `` to type `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.CategorVO] ``.

Any suggestions will help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Add `.ToList()` in the end?

Comment: Are the objects in myList1 the same type as the objects in myList2?

Comment: Do you want to compare the list object as a whole or the individual items in the list?

Comment: When you say "difference" do you mean the result should only contain those items in myList1 that do not appear in myList2 AND those items in myList2 that do not appear in myList2?

Comment: Hi @GSerg , yes this worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just adding ToList() at the end.

You query is also incorrect.

I think this is what you want:

```
myList3 = myList1.Where(Function(item) Not myList2.Any(Function(item2) item.ClassId = item2.Id)).ToList()
```

I have created a small app to test this:

```
Private Sub btStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btStart.Click
    Dim myList1 As New List(Of FirstStruct)
    myList1.Add(New FirstStruct(1))
    myList1.Add(New FirstStruct(2))
    myList1.Add(New FirstStruct(3))
    myList1.Add(New FirstStruct(4))
    myList1.Add(New FirstStruct(5))
    myList1.Add(New FirstStruct(6))

    Dim myList2 As New List(Of SecondStruct)
    myList2.Add(New SecondStruct(5))
    myList2.Add(New SecondStruct(6))
    myList2.Add(New SecondStruct(6))
    myList2.Add(New SecondStruct(7))
    myList2.Add(New SecondStruct(8))


    Dim myList3 As New List(Of FirstStruct)
    myList3 = myList1.Where(Function(item) Not myList2.Any(Function(item2) item.ClassId = item2.Id)).ToList()

End Sub

Public Class FirstStruct
    Public ClassId As Integer

    Public Sub New(_id As Integer)
        ClassId = _id
    End Sub
End Class
Public Structure SecondStruct
    Public Id As Integer
    Public Sub New(_id As Integer)
        Id = _id
    End Sub
End Structure
```

The result is a List(Of FirstStruct) with the first 4 elements of myList1